# Calling method of another activity from Asynctask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am getting Syntax error - *`"No enclosing instance of the type MainFragmentActivity is accessible in scope"`* in the method `buildReport` -

[image]

**buildReport Method -**

```
public void buildReport(View v)
{
    //Syntax error here
    new VerifyDialogue(MainFragmentActivity.this).execute(dateRange); 
}
```

**This is my AsyncTask class** -

```
class VerifyDialogue extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
public MainFragmentActivity activity;

public VerifyDialogue(MainFragmentActivity a)
{
    //this is how I am getting instance of another activity
    this.activity = a; 
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Initializing Please Wait");
    pDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}


protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    return "";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //there are records in the sync queue
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(
    ReportsTypeActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("User Records!");
    alert.setMessage("You have records on the server.");

    alert.setPositiveButton("FIX", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(
            DialogInterface dialog, 
            int whichButton) 
            {
      dialog.cancel();

        //Calling method of activity MainFragmentActivity
        activity.nonsyncscreen(); 
    }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();                 
}
```

Comment: I think you have missing "}" in your VerifyDialogue class so add "}" at last in VerifyDialogue class.

Comment: @Haresh - See update. Image attached. This is not missing "}" problem.

Comment: Pass getApplicationContext() instead of MainFragmentActivity.this

Comment: so `buildReport()` is a method of which class? and OP can not show dialog when he use `getApplicationContext()`... @Giridharan

Comment: MainFragmentActivity is fragment or activity ?

Comment: @GopalRao - `buildReport()` is the method of `class ReportsTypeActivity` which extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: @Haresh = `MainFragmentActivity` is the Activity for all fragments.

Comment: Try to use getActivity() instead of this MainFragmentActivity.this and also change MainFragmentActivity to Activity in async class.

Comment: @VedPrakash then use `new VerifyDialogue(ReportsTypeActivity.this).execute(dateRange);`

Comment: @GopalRao - `nonsyncscreen()` is the method of `MainFragmentActivity`, so I can't use `ReportsTypeActivity.this` like you mentioned. I need the instance of `MainFragmentActivity` somehow to call the method `nonsyncscreen()`. Check my code to see this method.

Comment: @Haresh - I can't use `getActivity()` as it will give the current activity which is `ReportsTypeActivity`. However I want the activity `MainFragmentActivity` in order to call method `nonsyncscreen()`. Check my code to see this method.

Comment: So here your `ReportsTypeActivity` class extends `MainFragmentActivity` right. Then you can access parent class method in sub class. Just make it as public method..

Comment: @GopalRao - No, `class ReportsTypeActivity extends FragmentActivity` and `class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity`. Both are activities. I just want to call method nonsyncscreen() of activity MainFragmentActivity from activity ReportsTypeActivity.

Comment: Then how can you access one Activity method in another Actiovity??? Consider redesigning your code... or make `nonsyncscreen()` method as `static` method if it is `Activity` instance independent...

Comment: if you want that object so badly, simply put it to public static variable...

Comment: @JohnnyAW - I thought of this idea. But the problem with this is my method contains too much of non-static variables and there references which are further non-static. So this will change the syntax errors saying - "Cannot make a static reference to...".

Comment: @VedPrakash it cant be actually... wait, i'll edit my answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `MainFragmentActivity.this` only in a nested class. so *"No enclosing instance of the type MainFragmentActivity is accessible in scope"* means your method `buildReport(View v)` is not in a nested class inside of `MainFragmentActivity`class

possible solution, pass an instance of `MainFragmentActivity` to constructor of `ReportsTypeActivity`

another possible solution:

Mainfragment class:

```
{ 
    private static MainFragmentActivity instance;

    public onCreate(...){
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainFragmentActivity getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

ReportsTypeActivity-class:

```
public void buildReport(View v)
{
    //Syntax error here
    new VerifyDialogue(MainFragmentActivity.getInstance()).execute(dateRange); 
}
```

EDIT: getInstance() should be static

Comment: Syntax error at `instance = this;` saying - `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ReportsTypeActivity to MainFragmentActivity`.

Comment: @VedPrakash `instance = this;` put this in the `MainFragmentActivity` class, not `ReportsTypeActivity`

Comment: @VedPrakash you're welcome,  btw. getInstance() should be static

Answer (score 0):

I have a running example...

```
new MatchStreamListTask(this, URL, listview).execute();
```

and if you add it externally you have to pass the context..

```
public class MainFragmentActivityTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    Activity context;

    ListView listview;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public MainFragmentActivityTask (Activity coontext,String URL,ListView listview ) 
    {
        this.context=coontext;

        this.URL=URL;

        this.listview=listview;
    }
```